# Python3.6: errors in properly displaying multiple animated graphs in tkinter using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, animation, matplotlib, tkinter

I am designing a tkinter GUI that will display process variables (temperature, humidity, fan speeds, etc.) corresponding to a module of a particle accelerator. I am having issues with displaying multiple animated figures at the same time. When the code below is executed, only one of the two animation functions is called properly (note that no error is thrown):

```
"""
tkinter GUI for module of particle accelerator

author: F. Curtis Mason
email: fcmasoniii@uchicago.edu

Feel free to use or modify this code, but please include the authorship.
"""

# tkinter and ttk are both imported. tkinter is the main GUI library that is to
# be employed in this code. ttk is a module that resides within tkinter, and
# provides many of the same widgets as tkinter, but with different styles.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# random is imported for use of randomizers in graphing dummy variables. time is
# utilized in order to graph process variables against some measure of time.
import random as rn
import time as tm

# matplotlib is the graphing library employed in this code.
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

# These imports allow for the creation of animated (live) graphs via
# matplotlib, and provide for the proper display of such graphs in tk GUIs. 
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, 
NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler

# The Epics library is imported, for obvious reasons.
# import epics as ep

# A pre-packaged graphing style is used for matplotlib figures.
style.use("seaborn-bright")

# Multiple figures are created; to each, a subplot is assigned.
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax11 = fig1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax12 = fig2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# Names are assigned to the process variables that will be used. Variables 
are grouped according to their appearance
# on particular tabs of the GUI.
"""pv0_t = ep.PV("TEM:Pixel:Ch0:T")
pv0_rh = ep.PV("TEM:Pixel:Ch0:RH")
pv1_t = ep.PV("TEM:Pixel:Ch1:T")
pv1_rh = ep.PV("TEM:Pixel:Ch1:RH")
pv2_t = ep.PV("TEM:Pixel:Ch2:T")
pv2_rh = ep.PV("TEM:Pixel:Ch2:RH")
pv3_t = ep.PV("TEM:Pixel:Ch3:T")
pv3_rh = ep.PV("TEM:Pixel:Ch3:RH")
pv4_t = ep.PV("TEM:Pixel:Ch4:T")
pv4_rh = ep.PV("TEM:Pixel:Ch4:RH")
pv5_t = ep.PV("TEM:Pixel:Ch5:T")
pv5_rh = ep.PV("TEM:Pixel:Ch5:RH")"""

# These lists are those upon which process variable values will be appended.
# If code calls for plotting empty data sets, an error is thrown. To avoid this
# issue, each list is supplied an appropriate initial value. In case the y-var-
# iable in question is yet to be configured, a default value of "0" is
# supplied.
x_temp_0 = [0]
y_temp_0 = [0]  # change to pv0_t.get()
x_rh_0 = [0]
y_rh_0 = [0]  # change to pv0_rh.get()

x_temp_1 = [0]
y_temp_1 = [0]
x_rh_1 = [0]
y_rh_1 = [0]

x_temp_2 = [0]
y_temp_2 = [0]
x_rh_2 = [0]
y_rh_2 = [0]

x_temp_3 = [0]
y_temp_3 = [0]
x_rh_3 = [0]
y_rh_3 = [0]

x_temp_4 = [0]
y_temp_4 = [0]
x_rh_4 = [0]
y_rh_4 = [0]

x_temp_5 = [0]
y_temp_5 = [0]
x_rh_5 = [0]
y_rh_5 = [0]

def animate_temp(t):
    """ Callback function for plotting pixel temperatures.

    Its single input (i) is the frame number. As of now, x-lists operate as the
    relative timestamp since initial execution of the code. Each time
    animate_temp() is called (frequency = 1 Hz), the last value of the x-list
    in question is incremented by one and appended to that list. Additionally,
    variables associated with pixels 1-5 will host dummy values until those
    pixels are configured. New values are appended to appropriate lists, and old
    values are deleted. It is crucial to clear the plot each time it is desired
    to plot updated list versions; otherwise, old plots will remain on the figure.
"""
    x_temp_0.append(x_temp_0[-1] + 1)
    y_temp_0.append(rn.randrange(1, 51, 1))
    x_temp_1.append(x_temp_1[-1] + 1)
    y_temp_1.append(rn.randrange(1, 51, 1))
    x_temp_2.append(x_temp_2[-1] + 1)
    y_temp_2.append(rn.randrange(1, 51, 1))
    x_temp_3.append(x_temp_3[-1] + 1)
    y_temp_3.append(rn.randrange(1, 51, 1))
    x_temp_4.append(x_temp_4[-1] + 1)
    y_temp_4.append(rn.randrange(1, 51, 1))
    x_temp_5.append(x_temp_5[-1] + 1)
    y_temp_5.append(rn.randrange(1, 51, 1))

    if len(x_temp_0) > 20:
        del x_temp_0[0]
        del y_temp_0[0]
        del x_temp_1[0]
        del y_temp_1[0]
        del x_temp_2[0]
        del y_temp_2[0]
        del x_temp_3[0]
        del y_temp_3[0]
        del x_temp_4[0]
        del y_temp_4[0]
        del x_temp_5[0]
        del y_temp_5[0]

    ax11.clear()
    ax11.plot(x_temp_0, y_temp_0)
    ax11.plot(x_temp_1, y_temp_1)
    ax11.plot(x_temp_2, y_temp_2)
    ax11.plot(x_temp_3, y_temp_3)
    ax11.plot(x_temp_4, y_temp_4)
    ax11.plot(x_temp_5, y_temp_5)
    plt.ylim(ymin = 0, ymax = 50)
    plt.title("TEM:Pixel:Ch[]:T")
    plt.xlabel("Seconds (s) Since Initiation")
    plt.ylabel("Temperature (Degrees Celcius)")
    plt.grid(True)

def animate_rh(i):
    """ Callback function for plotting pixel humidity values.

    This function is the analogue of "animate_temp" for rh values.
    """
    x_rh_0.append(x_rh_0[-1] + 1)
    y_rh_0.append(rn.randrange(1, 51, 1))
    x_rh_1.append(x_rh_1[-1] + 1)
    y_rh_1.append(rn.randrange(1, 51, 1))
    x_rh_2.append(x_rh_2[-1] + 1)
    y_rh_2.append(rn.randrange(1, 51, 1))
    x_rh_3.append(x_rh_3[-1] + 1)
    y_rh_3.append(rn.randrange(1, 51, 1))
    x_rh_4.append(x_rh_4[-1] + 1)
    y_rh_4.append(rn.randrange(1, 51, 1))
    x_rh_5.append(x_rh_5[-1] + 1)
    y_rh_5.append(rn.randrange(1, 51, 1))

    if len(x_rh_0) > 20:
        del x_rh_0[0]
        del y_rh_0[0]
        del x_rh_1[0]
        del y_rh_1[0]
        del x_rh_2[0]
        del y_rh_2[0]
        del x_rh_3[0]
        del y_rh_3[0]
        del x_rh_4[0]
        del y_rh_4[0]
        del x_rh_5[0]
        del y_rh_5[0]

    ax12.clear()
    ax12.plot(x_rh_0, y_rh_0)
    ax12.plot(x_rh_1, y_rh_1)
    ax12.plot(x_rh_2, y_rh_2)
    ax12.plot(x_rh_3, y_rh_3)
    ax12.plot(x_rh_4, y_rh_4)
    ax12.plot(x_rh_5, y_rh_5)
    plt.ylim(ymin = 0, ymax = 100)
    plt.title("TEM:Pixel:Ch[]:RH")
    plt.xlabel("Seconds (s) Since Initiation")
    plt.ylabel("Relative Humidity (%)")
    plt.grid(True)

class Manager():
    """ Creates a tkinter GUI that monitors the module and pixels.

    This class displays data pertinent to the upkeep of the module
    and its pixels. Temperatures of various locations of the
    hardware are (often) graphed, as are relative humidities.
    Fan speeds, electrical properties, and electrical channel
    control are also displayed/made accessible.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Event Manager")
        self.create_notebook()

    def create_notebook(self):

        self.root["padx"] = 5
        self.root["pady"] = 5

        notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
        frame01 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        frame02 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        notebook.add(frame01, text = "Pixel Health")
        notebook.add(frame02, text = "Tab 2")
        notebook.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        frame1 = ttk.Frame(frame01)
        frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        canvas11 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, frame1)
        canvas11.show()
        canvas11.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        canvas12 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, frame1)
        canvas12.show()
        canvas12.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        quit_button = ttk.Button(self.root, text = "Quit", command = self.root.destroy)
        quit_button.grid(row = 4, column = 3)

program = Manager()
ani_1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, animate_temp, interval = 1000)
ani_2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig2, animate_rh, interval = 1000)
program.root.mainloop()
```

However, I am aware that if I were to make each graph a subplot of a single figure and combine both animation callbacks into a single one, both graphs would be updated simultaneously, as desired. This in general, is not optimal, for it would decrease my general freedom to organize the widgets on the first tab. That is, if I were to make both graphs a subplot of the same figure, then they would necessarily both occupy the same square on the parent grid (whereas I want each plot to occupy a separate square of the grid; this will make easier the job of appropriate organization, when, say, only three graphs will be displayed on this page, in addition to other widgets).

Please note that portions of the code corresponding to the Epics library are currently commented out. This is because I have been building and testing the code on a platform that does not have access to Epics or any associated networks.

I apologize for the degree and manner in which portions of the code are commented; I was instructed to comment as if the reader is new to tkinter and python in general. Additionally, I apologize if the commenting style employed is unusual or if it makes the code difficult to read.

Thank you in advance,
Curtis M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `canvas11.show()` and `canvas12.show()`.

(If you show a figure once, it will be hard to manipulate afterwards.)

You may then modify your animating functions to actually work on the axes, they are supposed to. E.g. `plt.ylim()` will set the limits of the currently active axes, which is the last one being created in this case. Instead use the axes directly to manipulate its properties:

```
ax11.set_ylim(ymin = 0, ymax = 50)
ax11.set_title("TEM:Pixel:Ch[]:T")
ax11.set_xlabel("Seconds (s) Since Initiation")
ax11.set_ylabel("Temperature (Degrees Celcius)")
ax11.grid(True)
```

In general the code has a lot of redundancies in it. The following is a modified version of it, also showing how to animate more efficiently.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
else:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

import random as rn
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

style.use("seaborn-bright")

fig1, ax11 = plt.subplots()
ax11.set_ylim(ymin = 0, ymax = 50)
ax11.set_title("TEM:Pixel:Ch[]:T")
ax11.set_xlabel("Seconds (s) Since Initiation")
ax11.set_ylabel("Temperature (Degrees Celcius)")
ax11.grid(True)

fig2, ax12 = plt.subplots()
ax12.set_ylim(ymin = 0, ymax = 100)
ax12.set_title("TEM:Pixel:Ch[]:RH")
ax12.set_xlabel("Seconds (s) Since Initiation")
ax12.set_ylabel("Relative Humidity (%)")
ax12.grid(True)

tempx = [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
tempy = [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
rhx =   [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
rhy =   [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]

lines_temp = []
for i in range(5):
    lines_temp.append(ax11.plot([],[])[0])

lines_rh = []
for i in range(5):
    lines_rh.append(ax12.plot([],[])[0])


def animate(t, x, y, lines, ax):
    for i in range(5):
        x[i].append(x[i][-1] + 1)
        y[i].append(rn.randrange(1, 51, 1))

    if len(x[0]) > 20:
        for i in range(5):
            del x[i][0]
            del y[i][0]

    for i in range(5):
        lines[i].set_data(x[i],y[i])
        ax.relim()
        ax.autoscale_view()


class Manager():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Event Manager")
        self.create_notebook()

    def create_notebook(self):

        self.root["padx"] = 5
        self.root["pady"] = 5

        notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
        frame01 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        frame02 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        notebook.add(frame01, text = "Pixel Health")
        notebook.add(frame02, text = "Tab 2")
        notebook.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        frame1 = ttk.Frame(frame01)
        frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        canvas11 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, frame1)
        #canvas11.show()
        canvas11.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        canvas12 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, frame1)
        print canvas12
        #canvas12.show()
        canvas12.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        quit_button = ttk.Button(self.root, text = "Quit", 
                                 command = self.root.destroy)
        quit_button.grid(row = 4, column = 3)

program = Manager()
ani_1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, animate, interval = 1000, 
                                fargs=(tempx,tempy, lines_temp, ax11))
ani_2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig2, animate, interval = 1000, 
                                fargs=(rhx,rhy, lines_rh, ax12))
program.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That seemed to have fixed the issue of getting both graphs to animate! However, now, a new issue has arisen -- one of the graphs (the one displaying variables associated with temperatures) is not displaying its title or axis titles. How might this be fixed? The only difference between the updated code and its original counterpart is the absence of canvas11.show() and canvas 12.show().

Comment: I think the original did not have titles or labels in the first version either, right? I updated the answer.

Comment: I know this is a little old and this answer solved my current problem. However, I don't understand why removing the `canvas11.show()` and `canvas12.show()` works. I mean wouldn't removing it, lead the figures to not show in the first place? Anyone care to explain it in more detail?